# No output when running jshint

Tags: javascript, jshint

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 and have installed jshint using "sudo npm install jshint -g". However when running jshint in console with the commands:

```
$ jshint <.js file>
```

I observe no output after the command returns.

Doing:

```
$ which jshint
```

returns /usr/local/bin/jshint.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Then there are no errors.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried it with various javascript files an would expect at least some warnings. Perhaps there are settings I can configure for jshint to be more verbose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, had to install nodejs by downloading the package from the node js website rather than just using sudo apt-get install.